# Get innerHTML of an element in a bootstrap popover's HTML

Tags: javascript, html

I have created a bootstrap popover with the following JavaScript code:

```
po = $(info.el).popover({
        html: true,
        title: "<input type=\"text\" value=\""+info.event.title+"\" style=\"font-weight: 500;\" class=\"popover-text\" id=\"popover-title\">",
        trigger: "focus",
        sanitize: false,
        animation: false,
        content: function() {
          return createPopoverContent(info.event)
        }
```

where `createPopoverContent` is a function which returns a string of HTML for the content of the popover given an event object.

```js
function createPopoverContent(event) {
  var start = event.start;
  var end = event.end;
  var html = "";
  var timeDisplay = "";
  var dateDisplay = moment(start).format("MMM D[,] YYYY");
  if (!event.allDay) {
    timeDisplay += moment(start).format("h:mm A") + " to " + moment(end).format("h:mm A");
  }
  html += "<input type=\"text\" value=\""+event.extendedProps.description+"\" class=\"popover-text\">"
  html += "<br><input type=\"text\" value=\""+dateDisplay+"\" class=\"popover-text\">"
  html += "<br>"+timeDisplay
  html += "<hr style=\"margin: 0em;\">"
  html += "Type: " + "<input type=\"text\" value=\""+event.extendedProps.type+"\" class=\"popover-text\">"
  html += "<hr style=\"margin: 0em;\">"
  html += "<label for=\"notes\">Notes:</label>"
  html += "<div class=\"input-group\"><textarea id=\"notes\" class=\"form-control\" aria-label=\"With textarea\">asdf</textarea></div>"
  return html
}
```

I want the textarea to be a field which the user can edit, and later the text can be saved to a database. How can I access this text from the popover's HTML after it's creation?

Comment: Add the html file

Comment: `$('#notes').val()`?

Comment: @MoshFeu this accesses the notes tag of the greater HTML document the code is in, not the HTML of the popover which is in a separate bootstrap document.

Comment: No if you have only one element with the id `note` (what it should). If you have more than one, replace the id of one of them.

Comment: I'm saying it's searching for the note id in the wrong file. This comes up undefined as the other HTML file doesn't have any note ids.

Comment: @JosepPujadas What do you mean by "searching for the note id in the wrong file?" If this is all running on one page, there is effectively only one "file".

Comment: Do you mean that the popover runs inside an iframe and you want an access in the parent page?

Comment: @kmoser the popover is created using javascript but it's html comes from the bootstrap library, which I found out from inspecting it in the browser.